# Most efficient way to watch for mousemove, click, touch only when class

Tags: jquery

Whats the most efficient way to watch for `mousemove`, `click` or `touch` events, **ONLY** when a particular class is added to the body tag.

```
$(document).on('click mousemove touch', function() {
    console.log('event');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.hasClass`:

```
$(document).on('click mousemove touch', function() {
  if ($("body").hasClass("particular-class"))
    console.log('event');
});
```

Or, you can do this way:

```
$(document).on('click mousemove touch', 'body.particular-class', function() {
    console.log('event');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen. My worry with this is that every time the mouse is moved it would run to check if the class is there. Is this the most efficient way?

Comment: @ccdavies The second one, never even executes the `mousemove` when body doesn't have that class. Check it out. Most efficient.